# Making dynamic circular queue, elements output fine but program crashes?

Tags: c++

The program compiles just fine but when the output window comes up, it shows the elements i've outputed and then i hear a windows sound, and then it just stops.

I'm trying to enqueue elements into the circular queue, and it appears that they are being input just fine since the display function prints them out. Everything seems to make sense, but the program just sorta crashes, could anybody elaborate on why exactly it might be doing this? My code is below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std; 

template<class QueueElement>
class dynamic_queue
{
  public:
  dynamic_queue(int = 10);
  dynamic_queue(const dynamic_queue &);
  ~dynamic_queue();
  QueueElement *getHead();
  int getSize() const; 
  bool isEmpty()const; 
  int getCapacity();
  void display(ostream &out) const; 
  void enqueue(const QueueElement &value);
  void dequeue();
  bool swap(dynamic_queue &, dynamic_queue &);
  void clear();
  const dynamic_queue & operator=(const dynamic_queue &);
  friend ostream & operator<< <> (ostream &, const   
   dynamic_queue<dynamic_queue> &);
private:
  int ihead; 
  int itail; 
  int initial_capacity;
  int array_capacity;
  int array_size;
  QueueElement *myarray; 
};


template<class QueueElement>
dynamic_queue<QueueElement>::dynamic_queue(int n)
:ihead(0),itail(0)
{

  if (n <= 0)
  {
    initial_capacity = 1; 
  }
  else
  {
    initial_capacity = max(n, 1);       
  }
array_capacity = initial_capacity; 
myarray = new QueueElement(initial_capacity); 
array_size = initial_capacity;


}

template<class QueueElement>
dynamic_queue<QueueElement>::~dynamic_queue()
{
  delete[]myarray;
}

template<class QueueElement>

void dynamic_queue<QueueElement>::enqueue(const QueueElement &inserted_value 
)
{
  int newTail = (itail + 1) % array_capacity;
  if (newTail != ihead)
  {
    myarray[itail] = inserted_value;
    itail = newTail;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Queue is full" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  cout << "itail: " << itail << endl; 
  cout << "array size" << array_size << endl; 

}
template<class QueueElement>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & o, const dynamic_queue<QueueElement>    &output_elements)
{
o << output_elements;
return o;
}

template<class QueueElement>
void dynamic_queue<QueueElement>::display(ostream &out) const
{
for (int i = ihead;i != itail;i = (i + 1) % array_capacity)
{
    out << myarray[i] << " ";
    cout << endl; 
}
}

template<class QueueElement>

int dynamic_queue<QueueElement>::getSize() const
{
int count = 0; 
for (int i = 0;i <= array_capacity;i++)
{
    count++; 
}
return count; 
}
```

main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DynamicCircularQueue.h"

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    dynamic_queue<int> queue1(5);
    queue1.enqueue(10);
    queue1.enqueue(11);
    queue1.getSize();
    queue1.display(cout);


}
```

Comment: Which line is the crash occurring on?

Comment: seems to happen when enqueue function is called for the second time " queue1.enqueue(11);" ; line 10 of main function. That's what the D bugger tells me

Answer (score 0):

> myarray = new QueueElement(initial_capacity);

should be:

```
myarray = new QueueElement[initial_capacity];
```

Since queue-element is `int`, you were allocating an array of just one element, that is why your code crashed at the second call to `enqueue`.